# Token price API

Tags: token, api

Besides http://analytics.muesliswap.com/ticker - are there any other APIs that return token price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this from minswap:
https://api-mainnet-prod.minswap.org/coinmarketcap/v2/pairs

or this minswap blockfrost adapter:
https://github.com/minswap/blockfrost-adapter

Answer (score -1):

Definitely yes! For Cardano use the following CoinGecko API:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/cardano

Under `market_data.current_price` key you will find the current price of the fiat & cryptocurrency you want of $ADA.

[image]

For more info regarding the API. Read the docs https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation